# why is this equation not left aligned?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I wonder why all the multilines of the equation are not left aligned? I tried to use align instead but the equation got too long and I could not manage to break it.

```
 \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report} 
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{fouriernc}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage{amsthm}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{eqnarray*}
 N =&\frac{\theta _{1}-\theta _{2}}{f}\left( \left( \theta _{1}+\theta
 _{2}+t\right) x-fy\right) \frac{\theta _{1}-\theta _{3}}{f}\left( \left(
 \theta _{1}+\theta _{3}+t\right) x-fy\right) \frac{\theta _{2}-\theta _{3}}{f%
 }\left( \left( \theta _{2}+\theta _{3}+t\right) x-fy\right)  \\
=&\frac{\left( \theta _{1}-\theta _{2}\right) \left( \theta _{1}-\theta
_{3}\right) \left( \theta _{2}-\theta _{3}\right) }{f^{3}}\left( \left(
\theta _{1}+\theta _{2}+t\right) x-fy\right) \left( \left( \theta
_{1}+\theta _{3}+t\right) x-fy\right) \left( \left( \theta _{2}+\theta
_{3}+t\right) x-fy\right)  \\
=&\frac{\sqrt{discr\left( \phi \right) }}{f^{3}}\left( \left( \theta
_{1}+\theta _{2}+t\right) x-fy\right) \left( \left( \theta _{1}+\theta
_{3}+t\right) x-fy\right) \left( \left( \theta _{2}+\theta _{3}+t\right)
x-fy\right) \\
=&\sqrt{discr\left( \phi \right) }\left( \frac{t^{3}-2pt^{2}+\left(
p^{2}+q\right) t+\left( r-qp\right) }{f^{3}}x^{3}-\frac{3t^{2}-4pt+\left(
p^{2}+q\right) }{f^{2}}x^{2}y+\frac{3t-2p}{f}xy^{2}-y^{3}\right) 
\end{eqnarray*}
```

and the output

[image]

Using `\begin{align*}` the equation exceeds the margins

[image]

Comment: Use `\begin{align*}...\end{align*}` instead of `eqnarray*` and change `=&` into `&=`.

Comment: I did that, but then the second and the last line become too wide and I am unable to split them. Somehow \begin{eqnarray*} ''squeezes'' everything so it fits within the margins of the page.

Comment: You should replace `discr` (five successive variables denoted by d, i, s, c, r) with `\discr` after you've added to the preamble `\DeclareMathOperator\discr{discr}`.

Comment: Don't use `eqnarray` at all. See, e.g., [Avoid eqnarray!](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-1/tb103madsen.pdf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have too many useless `\left` and `\right`. You also should be using `split` instead of `eqnarray*`. The fractions can be managed with `\tfrac` that makes them smaller.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
N
&= \tfrac{\theta_{1}-\theta_{2}}{f}
     ((\theta_{1}+\theta_{2}+t) x-fy)\,
   \tfrac{\theta_{1}-\theta_{3}}{f}
     ((\theta_{1}+\theta_{3}+t) x-fy)\,
   \tfrac{\theta_{2}-\theta_{3}}{f}
     (( \theta_{2}+\theta_{3}+t) x-fy)
\\
&= \tfrac{(\theta_{1}-\theta_{2})(\theta_{1}-\theta_{3})(\theta_{2}-\theta_{3})}{f^{3}}
     ((\theta_{1}+\theta_{2}+t) x-fy)\,
     ((\theta_{1}+\theta_{3}+t) x-fy)\,
     ((\theta_{2}+\theta_{3}+t) x-fy)
\\
&= \tfrac{\sqrt{\mathit{discr}(\phi)}}{f^{3}}
     ((\theta_{1}+\theta_{2}+t) x-fy)\,
     ((\theta_{1}+\theta_{3}+t) x-fy)\,
     ((\theta_{2}+\theta_{3}+t)x-fy)
\\
&= \sqrt{\mathit{discr}(\phi)}
   \left(
     \tfrac{t^{3}-2pt^{2}+(p^{2}+q) t+(r-qp)}{f^{3}}x^{3}-
     \tfrac{3t^{2}-4pt+(p^{2}+q)}{f^{2}}x^{2}y+
     \tfrac{3t-2p}{f}xy^{2}-y^{3}
   \right)
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would typeset it:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\discr}{discr}

\begin{document}

\noindent Let
\begin{equation*}
  g_{i,j}
  = (\theta_{i} + \theta_{j} + t)x - fy.
\end{equation*}
Then
\begin{align*}
  N
  &= \frac{\theta_{1} - \theta_{2}}{f}g_{1,2} \cdot
     \frac{\theta_{1} - \theta_{3}}{f}g_{1,3} \cdot
     \frac{\theta_{2} - \theta_{3}}{f}g_{2,3}\\
  &= \frac{(\theta_{1} - \theta_{2})
           (\theta_{1} - \theta_{3})
           (\theta_{2} - \theta_{3})}{f^{3}}
     \cdot g_{1,2} \, g_{1,3} \, g_{2,3}\\
  &= \frac{\sqrt{\discr(\phi)}}{f^{3}}
     \cdot g_{1,2} \, g_{1,3} \, g_{2,3}\\
  &= \sqrt{\discr(\phi)}
     \biggl(\frac{t^{3} - 2pt^{2} + (p^{2} + q)t + (r - qp)}{f^{3}}x^{3}\\
   &\hphantom{{}= \sqrt{\discr(\phi)}\biggl(}
    - \frac{3t^{2} - 4pt + (p^{2} + q)}{f^{2}}x^{2}y
    + \frac{3t - 2p}{f}xy^{2} - y^{3}\biggr)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Notice that I don't use any `\left`/`\right` constructions at all. Also, the space before the underscore is unnecessary, `discr` should (probably) be a mathematical operator, and [`eqnarray` is not a good environment](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-1/tb103madsen.pdf).

Comment: thank you, but as I tried to explain, then the expression exceeds the margins of the page. I have edited my post.

Comment: @user124471 That would have been nice to know before I did all the formatting!

Comment: Sorry but I wrote that above

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment you code as shown below

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
N &=\frac{\theta _{1}-\theta _{2}}{f}\left( \left( \theta _{1}+\theta
 _{2}+t\right) x-fy\right) \frac{\theta _{1}-\theta _{3}}{f}\left( \left(
 \theta _{1}+\theta _{3}+t\right) x-fy\right) \frac{\theta _{2}-\theta _{3}}{f%
 }\left( \left( \theta _{2}+\theta _{3}+t\right) x-fy\right)  \\
&=\frac{\left( \theta _{1}-\theta _{2}\right) \left( \theta _{1}-\theta
_{3}\right) \left( \theta _{2}-\theta _{3}\right) }{f^{3}}\left( \left(
\theta _{1}+\theta _{2}+t\right) x-fy\right) \left( \left( \theta
_{1}+\theta _{3}+t\right) x-fy\right) \left( \left( \theta _{2}+\theta
_{3}+t\right) x-fy\right)  \\
&=\frac{\sqrt{discr\left( \phi \right) }}{f^{3}}\left( \left( \theta
_{1}+\theta _{2}+t\right) x-fy\right) \left( \left( \theta _{1}+\theta
_{3}+t\right) x-fy\right) \left( \left( \theta _{2}+\theta _{3}+t\right)
x-fy\right) \\
&=\sqrt{discr\left( \phi \right) }\left( \frac{t^{3}-2pt^{2}+\left(
p^{2}+q\right) t+\left( r-qp\right) }{f^{3}}x^{3}-\frac{3t^{2}-4pt+\left(
p^{2}+q\right) }{f^{2}}x^{2}y+\frac{3t-2p}{f}xy^{2}-y^{3}\right) 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: leftadjusted]